# Max/Min principles of Helmhotz-like equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega  \subset {R^n}$ be a bounded domain and $u \in {C^2}\left( \Omega  \right) \cap {C^0}\left( {\bar \Omega } \right)$.  Which ones of the following 6 equalities and inequalities have the maximum or minimum principles?

I tried answering (2), (4) and (6).  Please help.

(1) $\Delta u\left( x \right) + u\left( x \right) = 0$   in $\Omega $  ${\rm{  }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}$ ?

(2) $\Delta u\left( x \right) - u\left( x \right) = 0$   in $\Omega $    $ \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\mathop {\max }\limits_{\bar U} u = \mathop {\max }\limits_{\partial U} u{\rm{ }},{\rm{ }}\mathop {\min u}\limits_{\bar U}  = \mathop {\min u}\limits_{\partial U} $
(3) $\Delta u\left( x \right) + u\left( x \right) \ge 0$  in  $\Omega {\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}$  ?

(4) $\Delta u\left( x \right) - u\left( x \right) \ge 0$   in $\Omega $    $ \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\mathop {\max }\limits_{\bar U} u = \mathop {\max }\limits_{\partial U} u{\rm{ }}$
(5) $\Delta u\left( x \right) + u\left( x \right) \le 0$  in  $\Omega {\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}$  ?

(6) $\Delta u\left( x \right) - u\left( x \right) \le 0$   in $\Omega $   ${\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{    }}\mathop {\min u}\limits_{\bar U}  = \mathop {\min u}\limits_{\partial U} $

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the first one doesn't have a min/max principle. Consider that equation in 1 dimension with domain $[0, 2\pi]$. One solution is given by $u(x) = \sin(x)$ depending on boundary conditions but the max and min don't occur on the boundary. Likewise, (3) and (5) won't have min/max principles. As far as the other ones, I'm fairly certain you are correct.